# Making big Machine Learning models on 4 GB RAM Laptop

Tags: python, machine-learning, freeze, ram

I have want to create a Digit Recognition Classifier using MNIST dataset. But whenever I train the classifier, due large size of dataset, my laptop freezes. But, somehow I managed to train the classifier and dumped into joblib file. This joblib file has a size of 377 MB. So, whenever I load the classifier to get the accuracy or predict the test values, my laptop freezes and I have to restart it again.
I also used the following command so that I don't have to store the classifier and not use much RAM:

```
from joblib import load
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
accuracy = cross_val_score(load(Digit Recognizer.joblib), x_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
```

But, this also didn't work and my laptop freezes. How can work with such a large classifier with just 4 GB RAM?

Comment: MNIST is by no means large.

Comment: Well, I know MNIST is not large in Machine Learning and I also don't have any problem in importing the dataset. But I have problem with the model I trained. Whenever I load that model, my laptop freezes.